# How to assign memory images to a DLIB array2d or image?

Tags: c++, dlib

This is likely more of a c++ question, but it does relate to DLIB. I am using another library to load images into memory (Leadtools). I want to replace the "load_image" function with assignments, but I am having trouble figuring out how to do so. I have all the information and memory allocated I need from my load, such as pixel bit depth, width, height, width_step, rgb/bgr order, and a pointer to the data.

So in the sample, there is:

```
array2d<bgr_pixel> img;
```

I can do this:

```
img.set_size(mywidth, myheight);
```

But (assuming the data mypointer is bgr contiguous char * bytes):

```
img.data = mydatapointer;
```

does not work - there is no img.data, plus I can't figure out how to use image_view.

What is the right way to setup that data pointer? Note that I do NOT want to duplicate memory :-)

Is there anything else that needs setting in order to simulate the load_image and have the correct structure to use within dlib?

TIA

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe this is possible. I glanced through the dlib source and the data pointer is private. Doesn't seem like there is any way to set it or retrieve it directly.

Comment: I would recommend digging in the source yourself, or contacting the developer of dlib, Davis King.

Comment: Dlib easily supports this.  If you want to do this you need to define the appropriate generic image interface for whatever image object you want to use. See: http://dlib.net/dlib/image_processing/generic_image.h.html

Comment: @Davis -Thanks, I get the idea, but the details are beyond my C++ skills. Not even sure how to get started with a template. Where would I place such a structure? I can fill in the bits to return the appropriate values (eg num row, the pointer etc.) The data is one of the standard pixel traits (either rgb, rgba etc). Any help in with this appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't even need to be a template.  In any case, you need to learn C++ before you can use C++.  This thing we are talking about is one of the most basic C++ programming tasks you could imagine.  So if you can't do this then you need to get a C++ book and learn C++, like one of these: http://dlib.net/books.html

Answer (score 2):

Based on Davis King's comment.

To avoid copying data from your own image structure to dlib internal format, dlib allows you to implement a generic image interface that will allows dlib to use directly your image. The interface that needs to be implemented looks like this:

```
    In dlib, an "image" is any object that implements the generic image interface.  In
    particular, this simply means that an image type (let's refer to it as image_type
    from here on) has the following seven global functions defined for it:
        - long        num_rows      (const image_type& img)
        - long        num_columns   (const image_type& img)
        - void        set_image_size(      image_type& img, long rows, long cols)
        - void*       image_data    (      image_type& img)
        - const void* image_data    (const image_type& img)
        - long        width_step    (const image_type& img)
        - void        swap          (      image_type& a, image_type& b)
     And also provides a specialization of the image_traits template that looks like:
        namespace dlib
        {
            template <> 
            struct image_traits<image_type>
            {
                typedef the_type_of_pixel_used_in_image_type pixel_type;
            };
        }
```

You can find more details here:
http://dlib.net/dlib/image_processing/generic_image.h.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by spending a lot more time with DLIB. Has nothing to do with C++. I rarely use templates so it was overwhelming at first.

What one needs to do is create some headers that follow the generic image model, as suggested. I chose to use array2d as the guide. By creating similar headers, along with adding a function to map to the image I have in memory, I was able to use the image data without duplicating it.

BTW the one gotcha, be careful about width_step (number of bytes per line). I had to set that since many images I had were padded. See code below.

To save someone a lot of time, here's what I did, naming the new structure arrayEd. Just used arrayEd instead of array3d.

If anyone has any comments on this code, it's welcomed :-)

arrayEd.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "arrayEd_kernel.h"
#include "serialize_pixel_overloads_arrayEd.h"
#include "arrayEd_generic_image.h"
```

For serialize_pixel_overloads_arrayEd.h, just replaced array3d with arrayEd.

arrayEd_kernel.h: (the bulk of changes). Added function setup and passed it my memory image class, along with a couple of variables to keep track of things.

```
#pragma once
// Copyright (C) 2006  Davis E. King (davis@dlib.net)
// License: Boost Software License   See LICENSE.txt for the full license.

#include "C:\VStudioProjects\dlib-master\dlib/algs.h"
#include "C:\VStudioProjects\dlib-master\dlib/interfaces/enumerable.h"
#include "C:\VStudioProjects\dlib-master\dlib/serialize.h"
#include "C:\VStudioProjects\dlib-master\dlib/geometry/rectangle.h"

namespace dlib
{
template <
    typename T,
    typename mem_manager = default_memory_manager
>
    class arrayEd : public enumerable<T>
{

    /*!
    INITIAL VALUE
    - nc_ == 0
    - nr_ == 0
    - data == 0
    - at_start_ == true
    - cur == 0
    - last == 0

    CONVENTION
    - nc_ == nc()
    - nr_ == nc()
    - if (data != 0) then
    - last == a pointer to the last element in the data array
    - data == pointer to an array of nc_*nr_ T objects
    - else
    - nc_ == 0
    - nr_ == 0
    - data == 0
    - last == 0


    - nr_ * nc_ == size()
    - if (cur == 0) then
    - current_element_valid() == false
    - else
    - current_element_valid() == true
    - *cur == element()

    - at_start_ == at_start()
    !*/


    class row_helper;
public:

    // These typedefs are here for backwards compatibility with older versions of dlib.
    typedef arrayEd kernel_1a;
    typedef arrayEd kernel_1a_c;

    typedef T type;
    typedef mem_manager mem_manager_type;

    // -----------------------------------
    bool bIsAllocatedHere;  //ec this is used to tell whether or not the memory came from here - if so, we clean it up.
    long lWidthStep;   // number of bytes in a row. This comes from leadtools and is set when we setup the image in setup()

    class row
    {
        /*!
        CONVENTION
        - nc_ == nc()
        - for all x < nc_:
        - (*this)[x] == data[x]
        !*/

        friend class arrayEd<T, mem_manager>;
        friend class row_helper;

    public:
        long nc(
        ) const {
            return nc_;
        }

        const T& operator[] (
            long column
            ) const
        {
            // make sure requires clause is not broken
            DLIB_ASSERT(column < nc() && column >= 0,
                "\tconst T& arrayEd::operator[](long column) const"
                << "\n\tThe column index given must be less than the number of columns."
                << "\n\tthis:    " << this
                << "\n\tcolumn:  " << column
                << "\n\tnc(): " << nc()
            );

            return data[column];
        }

        T& operator[] (
            long column
            )
        {
            // make sure requires clause is not broken
            DLIB_ASSERT(column < nc() && column >= 0,
                "\tT& arrayEd::operator[](long column)"
                << "\n\tThe column index given must be less than the number of columns."
                << "\n\tthis:    " << this
                << "\n\tcolumn:  " << column
                << "\n\tnc(): " << nc()
            );

            return data[column];
        }

    private:

        row(T* data_, long cols) : data(data_), nc_(cols) {}

        T* data;
        long nc_;


        // restricted functions
        row() {}
        row& operator=(row&);
    };

    // -----------------------------------

    arrayEd(
    ) :
        data(0),
        nc_(0),
        nr_(0),
        cur(0),
        last(0),
        at_start_(true),
        bIsAllocatedHere(false),
        lWidthStep(0)
    {
    }

    arrayEd(
        long rows,
        long cols
    ) :
        data(0),
        nc_(0),
        nr_(0),
        cur(0),
        last(0),
        at_start_(true),
        bIsAllocatedHere(false),
        lWidthStep(0)
    {
        // make sure requires clause is not broken
        DLIB_ASSERT((cols >= 0 && rows >= 0),
            "\t arrayEd::arrayEd(long rows, long cols)"
            << "\n\t The arrayEd can't have negative rows or columns."
            << "\n\t this: " << this
            << "\n\t cols: " << cols
            << "\n\t rows: " << rows
        );

        set_size(rows, cols);
    }

#ifdef DLIB_HAS_RVALUE_REFERENCES
    arrayEd(arrayEd&& item) : arrayEd()
    {
        swap(item);
    }

    arrayEd& operator= (
        arrayEd&& rhs
        )
    {
        swap(rhs);
        return *this;
    }
#endif

    virtual ~arrayEd(
    ) {
        clear();
    }

    long nc(
    ) const {
        return nc_;
    }

    long nr(
    ) const {
        return nr_;
    }

    row operator[] (
        long row_
        )
    {
        // make sure requires clause is not broken
        DLIB_ASSERT(row_ < nr() && row_ >= 0,
            "\trow arrayEd::operator[](long row_)"
            << "\n\tThe row index given must be less than the number of rows."
            << "\n\tthis:     " << this
            << "\n\trow_:      " << row_
            << "\n\tnr(): " << nr()
        );

        return row(data + row_*nc_, nc_);
    }

    const row operator[] (
        long row_
        ) const
    {
        // make sure requires clause is not broken
        DLIB_ASSERT(row_ < nr() && row_ >= 0,
            "\tconst row arrayEd::operator[](long row_) const"
            << "\n\tThe row index given must be less than the number of rows."
            << "\n\tthis:     " << this
            << "\n\trow_:      " << row_
            << "\n\tnr(): " << nr()
        );

        return row(data + row_*nc_, nc_);
    }

    void swap(
        arrayEd& item
    )
    {
        exchange(data, item.data);
        exchange(nr_, item.nr_);
        exchange(nc_, item.nc_);
        exchange(at_start_, item.at_start_);
        exchange(cur, item.cur);
        exchange(last, item.last);
        pool.swap(item.pool);
    }

    void clear(
    )
    {
        if (data != 0)
        {
            // ec we might manage this memory at the leadtools level 
            if (bIsAllocatedHere)
                pool.deallocate_array(data);
            nc_ = 0;
            nr_ = 0;
            data = 0;
            at_start_ = true;
            cur = 0;
            last = 0;
            bIsAllocatedHere = false;
        }
    }

    void set_size(
        long rows,
        long cols
    );

    bool at_start(
    ) const {
        return at_start_;
    }

    void reset(
    ) const {
        at_start_ = true; cur = 0;
    }

    bool current_element_valid(
    ) const {
        return (cur != 0);
    }

    const T& element(
    ) const
    {
        // make sure requires clause is not broken
        DLIB_ASSERT(current_element_valid() == true,
            "\tconst T& arrayEd::element()()"
            << "\n\tYou can only call element() when you are at a valid one."
            << "\n\tthis:    " << this
        );

        return *cur;
    }

    T& element(
    )
    {
        // make sure requires clause is not broken
        DLIB_ASSERT(current_element_valid() == true,
            "\tT& arrayEd::element()()"
            << "\n\tYou can only call element() when you are at a valid one."
            << "\n\tthis:    " << this
        );

        return *cur;
    }

    bool move_next(
    ) const
    {
        if (cur != 0)
        {
            if (cur != last)
            {
                ++cur;
                return true;
            }
            cur = 0;
            return false;
        }
        else if (at_start_)
        {
            cur = data;
            at_start_ = false;
            return (data != 0);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    unsigned long size(
    ) const {
        return static_cast<unsigned long>(nc_ * nr_);
    }

    long width_step(
    ) const
    {
        if (lWidthStep == 0)  // inc ase image not allocated by leadtools
            return nc_ * sizeof(T);
        else
            return lWidthStep;
    }

    // eds setup fcn
    int setup(CpwImage& img)
    {
        data = (T *)img.AccessBitmap();
        nc_ = img.GetWidth();
        nr_ = img.GetHeight();
        cur = last = 0;
        at_start_ = (true);
        lWidthStep = img.GetBytesPerLine();
        if (data != 0)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

private:


    T* data;
    long nc_;
    long nr_;

    typename mem_manager::template rebind<T>::other pool;
    mutable T* cur;
    T* last;
    mutable bool at_start_;

    // restricted functions
    arrayEd(arrayEd&);        // copy constructor
    arrayEd& operator=(arrayEd&);    // assignment operator

};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <
    typename T,
    typename mem_manager
>
    inline void swap(
        arrayEd<T, mem_manager>& a,
        arrayEd<T, mem_manager>& b
    ) {
    a.swap(b);
}


template <
    typename T,
    typename mem_manager
>
    void serialize(
        const arrayEd<T, mem_manager>& item,
        std::ostream& out
    )
{
    try
    {
        // The reason the serialization is a little funny is because we are trying to
        // maintain backwards compatibility with an older serialization format used by
        // dlib while also encoding things in a way that lets the arrayEd and matrix
        // objects have compatible serialization formats.
        serialize(-item.nr(), out);
        serialize(-item.nc(), out);

        item.reset();
        while (item.move_next())
            serialize(item.element(), out);
        item.reset();
    }
    catch (serialization_error e)
    {
        throw serialization_error(e.info + "\n   while serializing object of type arrayEd");
    }
}

template <
    typename T,
    typename mem_manager
>
    void deserialize(
        arrayEd<T, mem_manager>& item,
        std::istream& in
    )
{
    try
    {
        long nr, nc;
        deserialize(nr, in);
        deserialize(nc, in);

        // this is the newer serialization format
        if (nr < 0 || nc < 0)
        {
            nr *= -1;
            nc *= -1;
        }
        else
        {
            std::swap(nr, nc);
        }

        item.set_size(nr, nc);

        while (item.move_next())
            deserialize(item.element(), in);
        item.reset();
    }
    catch (serialization_error e)
    {
        item.clear();
        throw serialization_error(e.info + "\n   while deserializing object of type arrayEd");
    }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// member function definitions
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <
    typename T,
    typename mem_manager
>
    void arrayEd<T, mem_manager>::
    set_size(
        long rows,
        long cols
    )
{
    // make sure requires clause is not broken
    DLIB_ASSERT((cols >= 0 && rows >= 0),
        "\tvoid arrayEd::set_size(long rows, long cols)"
        << "\n\tThe arrayEd can't have negative rows or columns."
        << "\n\tthis: " << this
        << "\n\tcols: " << cols
        << "\n\trows: " << rows
    );

    // set the enumerator back at the start
    at_start_ = true;
    cur = 0;

    // don't do anything if we are already the right size.
    if (nc_ == cols && nr_ == rows)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (data != 0)
    {
        DLIB_ASSERT(0, "Something wrong - this csoi image type should not be REsetting size");
        return;
    }

    nc_ = cols;
    nr_ = rows;

    // free any existing memory
    if (data != 0)
    {
        pool.deallocate_array(data);
        data = 0;
    }

    // now setup this object to have the new size
    try
    {
        if (nr_ > 0)
        {
            data = pool.allocate_array(nr_*nc_);
            last = data + nr_*nc_ - 1;
            bIsAllocatedHere = true;
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        if (data)
            pool.deallocate_array(data);

        data = 0;
        nc_ = 0;
        nr_ = 0;
        last = 0;
        throw;
    }
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename T>
struct is_arrayEd : public default_is_kind_value
{
    /*!
    - if (T is an implementation of array2d/array2d_kernel_abstract.h) then
    - is_array2d<T>::value == true
    - else
    - is_array2d<T>::value == false
    !*/
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename T, typename MM>
struct is_arrayEd <arrayEd<T, MM> >
{
    const static bool value = true;
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

}

Comment: This is not at all a reasonable way to do this. All you need to do is define the generic image global functions for your image class, CpwImage. Don't make a new class, especially one that is a copy paste of another whose implementation you don't understand.